# how to get back some text from a calling activity

Tags: android, android-intent, actionresult, start-activity

I have an activity that Call another activity for filling an address and second activity should send back the address for the first activity and show it in a textview in first activity

i used these codes
but i dont know why it s not working

first activity:

```
 Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShippingActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RESULT_OK){
            tvDeliverTo.setText(data.getStringExtra("DeliveryAdressKEY"));
        }
    }
```

and second activity

```
   Intent in = new Intent();
    in.putExtra("DeliveryAdressKEY", tvAdress.getText().toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, in);
    finish();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use StartActivityForResult not StartActivity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the second activity with `startActivityForResult`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

In `onActivityResult`, you should also check the `resultCode` is `RESULT_OK`, rather than the `requestCode`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity().

Answer (score 0):

first activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShippingActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(in, 0);


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 0){
            if(resultCode ==1){
tvDeliverTo.setText(data.getStringExtra("DeliveryAdressKEY"));              
            }
        }
    }
```

and second activity

```
Intent in = new Intent();
in.putExtra("DeliveryAdressKEY", tvAdress.getText().toString());
setResult(1, in);
finish();
```

and now is working